# How to display matrix and being able to print out each element of the matrix correctly in C/C++?

Tags: c, arrays

I was doing my code and ran into a problem where I was able to print out my 2D array/matrix but when I went and print out each element, the output only consisted of the bottom row of the matrix repeated. Here is my code and an example of the input and output of my code.

```
int main()
{
int r = 2;
int c = 2;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int a[i][j];

for(i = 0; i <= r; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j <= c; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

printf("%d\n", a[0][0]);
printf("%d\n", a[0][1]);
printf("%d\n", a[0][2]);
printf("%d\n", a[1][0]);
printf("%d\n", a[1][1]);
printf("%d\n", a[1][2]);
printf("%d\n", a[2][0]);
printf("%d\n", a[2][1]);
printf("%d\n", a[2][2]);

return 0;
}

Example of the matrix being printed with a random number generator:

12 34 67
48 37 42
93 42 13

Example of each element being printed:

93
42
13
93
42
13
93
42
13
```

Comment: `int a[i][j];` Did you mean `int a[r][c];`?

Comment: yes i did mean int a[r][c]; Also, I used a rand function to print out the outputs so the real outputs would be random.

Comment: This is not C++.  `int a[r][c]` is not valid C++ syntax.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But the question is tagged with c

Comment: The code is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by compile-time constant, not a runtime expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you declare the array as a[i][j] with i=0,j=0;

declare the array as a[3][3]; will avoid this problem. The array size needs to be declared with maximum number of elements.

Comment: @Bursidaer You can also set `r` and `c` to `3` to make it more readable. And remove the `=` in those loop headers.